# If I create a web app with ReactJS, can I reuse the code to build a mobile app with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, web-applications, react-native

Do I get an advantage by using ReactJS for frontend if I'm planning to create mobile apps with React Native (maybe much faster development since some of the code can be reused)?

Or it does it not matter if it is ReactJS, Vue or Angular 2, as long I use Javascript so that I still can reuse the code for React native?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, but you have to adopt Higher Order Components (HOC) Stateless Functional Components in order to fully reuse your code.

The Difference:
[image: Screenshot of the difference]

Basically, ReactJS and React Native are almost identical, except for their component. Therefore, the best way to reuse code is to create separate independent components using HOC which can be called from both side using stateless functional component.

https://hackernoon.com/code-reuse-using-higher-order-hoc-and-stateless-functional-components-in-react-and-react-native-6eeb503c665

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [platform-specific extensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions) feature of React Native to automatically load the platform specific javascript modules. Then you need to put all your common code in a regular javascript modules and provide platform specific implementations in modules with corresponding extensions.

You can check how to do that here [Code sharing between React and React Native applications](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/code-sharing-between-react-and-react-native-applications/)